# Como criar app para android com Html5

Tags: android, html5

Quero iniciar um app com html5 que fique tipo um blog aonde possar publicar tutoriais por parte mas que seja no app como poderia fazer isso em html5.

O exemplo abaixo de como o app seria.

Cada bloco da primeira tabela é um tema e quando eu clico no tema apareça os tutoriais dele.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pesquisa sobre [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org), ai vai achar algumas variantes, a que eu uso atualmente é a [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started), que tem base no Angular.

Comment: Você poderia usar o IONIC para criar a aplicação, veja a documentação do [IONIC](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3mZ6ArP7RAhVBfZAKHa_GDbMQFgglMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fionicframework.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFs_Vi2jRGpAkX2cqIN0vXtw-ERgA&sig2=QX8AlB7OWaG7qb4r3MkbOg). Ele possui muitos recursos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem muitas maneiras...

1 - Ionic (Android, IOS, WP) (http://ionicframework.com/)

2 - Xamarin (Android, IOS, WP) (https://www.xamarin.com/)

3 -  Ou usar WebView  (Android) - Nesse vc faz sua aplicação usando HTML, CSS e JavaScript, depois de pronta so chamar a aplicação na WebView.
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Tem outras formas...